# Why does assigning to `NaN` or `undefined` cause a TypeError?

Tags: javascript, typeerror

*A.S.: The question is about type of error, not about the phenomenon*

`"use strict"` throws TypeError if system variables like `NaN` and `undefined` got changed.
But why is it a **Type**Error? Why not **Syntax**Error?

---

*Edit:* Really, it is not the SyntaxError here since there are no errors in syntax of the snippet.
But the root of the error lies in the fact, that some *protected object cannot be changed* manually; so, it is lkely the **Access**Error (there are no such, I know).
Then, why access-errors appear like type-ones?

Comment: Because they are (for all intents and purposes) properties of the global object (aka: variables)

Comment: It's not "protected". It's just read only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In ES5, there are 6 different kinds of [native errors](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.11.6):

- [EvalError](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.11.6.1)

  > This exception is not currently used within this specification. This
  >   object remains for compatibility with previous editions of this
  >   specification.
- [RangeError](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.11.6.2)

  > Indicates a numeric value has exceeded the allowable range.
- [ReferenceError](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.11.6.3)

  > Indicate that an invalid reference value has been detected.
- [SyntaxError](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.11.6.4)

  > Indicates that a parsing error has occurred.
- [TypeError](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.11.6.5)

  > Indicates the actual type of an operand is different than the expected
  >   type.
- [URIError](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.11.6.6)

  > Indicates that one of the global URI handling functions was used in a
  >   way that is incompatible with its definition.

In your case, the error is thrown because you attempt to assign a value to [`window.NaN`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.1.1) or [`window.undefined`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.1.3), which are non-writable properties.

Before assigning the new value, the internal [[[Put]]](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.12.5) method checks [[[CanPut]]](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.12.4), which will return false because the property is non-enumerable. And therefore [[Put]] will throw.

So the problem is that the writability of the assigned reference (left operand in the [assignment expression](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.13.1)) is not the expected one. Then, among the 6 error kinds above, the most appropriate seems TypeError, even if writability is not exactly a [type](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.1).

Comment: Note that `jsc` throws no error on assigning to NaN, and a ReferenceError on `1=2`: "Exception: ReferenceError: Left side of assignment is not a reference." Since `typeof(NaN)`=`typeof(1)`=`number`, a reference error might indeed be more appropriate.

Comment: @MichaelBar-Sinai No, because `NaN` is an identifier which can be [resolved](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.3.1) to the [reference](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.7) `{base: globalObject, referencedName: "NaN", strictFlag: whatever}`. Then ReferenceError wouldn't be appropriate. `1` is not an identifier so it can't be resolved to a reference, then `1=2` throws a ReferenceError. Note assignments to `NaN` [can potentially succeed](https://jsfiddle.net/vfpgh4rq/), unlike assignments to `1`.

Comment: @Oriol this is just a regular variable. Nothing to see here move along.

Answer (score 2):

Because `NaN` and `undefined` are just **read only properties of `window`**. They are not operators (like `>` or `+`), or keywords (like `var` or `class`).

Trying to assign something to `NaN` gives the following error in Chrome:

> TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property '`NaN`' of object '`#<Window>`'

Comment: @ayushgp Node gives similar error: "TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'NaN' of #<Object>". That's because in Node `global` is the global object, and `Object` is its constructor.

Comment: @ayushgp: Doesn't Node have the same V8 JavaScript-engine as Google Chrome?

Comment: @DmitryParzhitsky Yes, the same engine, but not the same environment; node does not have `window` for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Because it's a valid argument that does not make sense. But it does not make sense in the SEMANTIC level, not the syntactic.

Here's an example:

```
1+1=42
```

This is wrong, but it's wrong in a different way than, say:

```
42 1 1 + =
```

You can read the first one as an arithmetic equation (one plus one equals forty-two). The second one, you can't even read.

The same goes here. the statement `NaN=300;` can be read in Javascript as "have `NaN` point to the value 300`. But when the parser submit this request to the engine, the **engine** goes "Nope, can't do this".

Comment: Thank you for answer. I've broadened the question.

Comment: The second one is [totally readable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) and means exactly the same as the first :-)

Comment: @Bergi I was about to link that!

Comment: @Bergi Oh dear. Totally missed that. I guess it's Michael: 0 Michael's sub conscious: 1.

Answer (score 0):

**syntax error**
In most programming & scripting languages this generally means that you've used an operator in the wrong place.
For more info on "syntax errors", have a look at this article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_error

**type error**
These occur when a data-type miss-matches some requirement.
For more information on "data-types", have a look at this article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_type

So, the *type error* is thrown because `NaN` and `undefined` are "data-types", which are global constants with a specific (designated) value, and "strict mode" prevents issues by not allowing to change these.

Comment: `NaN` and `undefined` cannot be changed in non-strict mode either.

Comment: It depends on which version of JavaScript (ES) you're using and also on which platform; like different browsers, NodeJS, etc.